# From pandas to excel via xlwings - do not deposit index

Tags: python, pandas, xlwings

```
Range("A1").value = p.df_sector[["A","B","C"]].sort(columns=["C"],ascending=False).head(4)
```

Works wonderfully! But - I do not want/need to see the `index` column

```
p.df_sector[["A","B","C"]].sort(columns=["C"],ascending=False).head(4).to_string(index=False)
```

Would do what I need, but then the data deposits in a single cell!

```
.to_matrix()
```

Does what I need but then I lose my headers (which I require).

Any input on how to dump the `df` **with**  headers and **without** index?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's an example in the [docs](http://docs.xlwings.org/datastructures.html#pandas-dataframes-and-series) about working with pandas. Also check the docs about [Range](https://docs.xlwings.org/en/latest/api/range.html). In your case:

```
sht.range("A1").options(index=False).value = p.df_sector[["A","B","C"]].sort(columns=["C"],ascending=False).head(4)
```

Comment: Please see answer from @lebelinoz for up to date syntax

Answer (score 7):

The documentation and syntax seems to have changed a bit, since 2015.

[Here](https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/converters.html#pandas-series-converter) is the documentation for dealing with Pandas via xlwings.

Instead of a parameter in `Range`, `index=False` needs to be inside a `.options`.  So if you're dealing with worksheet `sht` in your code, the left-hand side of your equation should be

```
sht.range('A1').options(index=True).value = ...
```